# Display all data from a certain range and sum the value of their right cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm not sure how to go about this since I'm still newbie at Excel and I only know how to COUNTIF in static lists. My problems are:

1. A8 and below - How to dynamically display the Tasks from a dynamic list (B3-B5, D3-D5, F3-F5 and so on and so forth)
2. B8 and below - How do I get the sum of Hours of each Task items?

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 3):

Assuming a range of `B2:K4`:

```
=LET(
    ζ, B2:K4,
    ξ, WRAPROWS(TOCOL(ζ), 2),
    γ, TAKE(ξ, , 1),
    δ, SORT(UNIQUE(γ)),
    HSTACK(δ, BYROW(δ, LAMBDA(ε, SUM((γ = ε) * TAKE(ξ, , -1)))))
)
```